# Best method to manage and link php files,

Tags: php, html, structure

I want to know which one is the best way to create a website. 
I've a 'Navigation Bar', Content Are' and 'Footer' in my website. since my website is fully dynamic so i want to load the 'Navigation Bar' and 'Footer' in most of the pages. So please suggest me the best and fastest way to do this task.

Example:

```
|----------------------|
|       Header         |   
|                      |
|======================-
|                      |\
|                      | \
|                      |  --->> Want to change this area, in different pages, Login, Signup, 
|       Content        | /      About Us, Contact etc.. but the header and footer remains 
|                      |/       same.
|                      |
|======================|
|       Footer         |
|----------------------|
```

Question: My header HTML code is too long and contains many things like slider, navigation bar and much jquery code associated with it. so if i copy it in all the pages would it make the pages lag? or shall i save header to separate files and footer to separate and include them with php?

Comment: What server technology do you have access to? PHP/JSP? if only client side, use jQuery/Ajax

Comment: Definitely. Use [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) to include header and footer files explicitly

Comment: I'm using php, jquery.. I don't know much about ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Your Structure will look like this,

**header.php**

```
|----------------------|
|       Header         |   
|======================|
```

**footer.php**

```
|======================|
|       Footer         |
|----------------------|
```

Now you need to include using `require_once` method.

**page1.php**

```
   require_once('header.php');

     // Body Content

   require_once('footer.php');
```

**page2.php**

```
   require_once('header.php');

     // Body Content

   require_once('footer.php');
```

Also for your `jQuery` or `js` codes create a file with `script.js` and paste in it. Now can able to include that file using this command `<script src="script.js" />`

Comment: Thanks, and is there any other possible way too? but not copying and pasting the header and footer in every page.

Comment: I don't think, is there any other better way to do using PHP.

Comment: Ok, Is it better or with ajax? or please tell me may i put head section too in header file?

Comment: Why ajax? Does your header section contains any dynamic content? Yes. Your <header> contain all the header related codes.

Comment: not header related codes, <head> above body.. where all the seo tags are. may i put it in header file?

Comment: Yeah. Sure. Am also mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery have this in an external file:

```
$(function() {
  $("#header").load("header.html");
  $("#footer").load("footer.html");
});
```

and have

```
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content">....</div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

You can then even swap the content

```
$(function() {
  $("#header").load("header.html",function() {
    $("#header").on("click",".navigation",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#content").load(this.href);
    });
    $("#login").click(); // load first content
  });
  $("#footer").load("footer.html");
});
```

where the hrefs of the links in the header point to login.html, about.html,

Answer (score 0):

If your header and footer are static, you can have one layout which will contain header and footer and you can include your dynamic content in it. That is the way lot of PHP frameworks do.

```
<?php

$page = (isset($_GET['page']) && !empty ($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] . '.php' : 'index.php';

?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>

        <?php include_once $page; ?>

        <footer></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Smells like iframe but what if i have the link in yourfile.php and i want to go to another page, then how may i change this include once.

Comment: use some variable include_once $yourFile; and in $yourFile you will have string which you will generate by your URL

Comment: in my code you can't find something like iframe, that is something too different

Comment: I've just updated my code, this is very simple way you can implement it